# How to pass source value to pre processing one at a time/iterate within the same taskflow?

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I’ve tried to assign source row value to InOut parameter/ Mapping variable using  SetVariable($$p_file_name, FileName).
But It does not update the value once set. I tried solutions from web : 
- SetVariable($$p_file_name, Null) ,
- Taskflow variable with assignment to the mapp variable, 
- splitting the mapping into 2 parts ( 1st gets the value in Mapp Var & 2nd tries to use it in pre processing cmd) ,
 —UserParameter file permanent sets the value & 
- Default value with a empty string.

Nothing worked consistently to update the Inout Parameter/Mapping Variable every time a row is read with a new value from source table.
Note : I’ve the run xcopy manually & it works from cmd prompt using the $$p_file_name as source.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to script with variables the manual xcopy you preformed. Admittedly there are many other solutions though maintaining your own script and variables will give you a consistent result.

Comment: I’m trying to do exactly that. But mapping variables in that script when called by post processing part of Informatica do not get the latest values. As it persist the mapp variables last value in repository and compares with the new values - if it is max then applies the new values else keep the old one. Same happens when Min is selected as Aggregation, which is a must pickwhen we create. Thanks Scott.

Comment: I should have been more explicit. Do not use an in-out parameter. Those are maintained by Informatica. Use a parameter file, which your script can edit pre or post, depending on your full solution. See https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/18/473608.aspx for more details on using parameter files.

Comment: Np. For source query or target, I know we can use the parameter file. But here I've to (a) just set within mapping using the incoming value & (b) use that $$param in Pre & Post-processing command box of mapping task. As that parameter is eventually passed to xcopy & run via Informatica in command prompt. Hope I'm able to clarify the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using parameters from the parameter file as inputs to pre or post processing scripts. Can you provide an example? Meanwhile, here are some good references: https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/22/572144.aspx, https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/21/527137.aspx, https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/19/497375.aspx

Comment: I was able to achieve it in 2 parts : (a) mapping that would read an excel, copy the data into a common excel & rename it. (b) loading the data from file to table. In (a), I was able to read one row at a time, use set variable and write the User parameter file, which was then used immediately by the Post-processing command. the last part was a challenge all along. Big thanks to Scott S Nelson(@scott-s-nelson) for pointing me in that direction